# How to disable JButton without hiding its label?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm developing a project in Java using netbeans IDE and I need to disable a particular JButton. I use the following code for that.

```
IssuBtn.setEnabled(false);
```

But after it is disabled it doesn't show the text on the JButton. How can I keep that text on the JButton?

Comment: `setEnabled(false)` do not remove text from button you must have some other bug in your code.

Comment: Could you please post SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) as this is something unusual. Thanks

Comment: Typically the text is still there, albeit greyed out with different shading.  Are you sure that's not the case?  If so, what look and feel are you using, or if you're using the standard, what operating system and window manager are you using?

Comment: To Harry Joy. But when I do that it removes the text it doesn't show any bug on the project as well.

Comment: Post SSCCE that reflects the same behavior.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: something's wrong with your setup somewhere - never seen such a coloring scheme (before running @Andrew's example - so it's possible to produce in crazy corner cases :-) You have to dig and find the underlying reason

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This experiment suggests one answer is 'Use a PLAF that is not Metal'.

[image: Look Of Disabled Buttons]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class LookOfDisabledButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
                JPanel pEnabled = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0,2,2));
                pEnabled.setBackground(Color.green);
                gui.add(pEnabled, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                JPanel pDisabled = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0,2,2));
                pDisabled.setBackground(Color.red);
                gui.add(pDisabled, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] plafs = 
                    UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
                for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo plafInfo : plafs) {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(plafInfo.getClassName());
                        JButton bEnabled = new JButton(plafInfo.getName());
                        pEnabled.add(bEnabled);
                        JButton bDisabled = new JButton(plafInfo.getName());
                        bDisabled.setEnabled(false);
                        pDisabled.add(bDisabled);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Alternately, adjust the values in the `UIManager`.

[image: UIManager tweak]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class LookOfDisabledButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
                JPanel pEnabled = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0,2,2));
                pEnabled.setBackground(Color.green);
                gui.add(pEnabled, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                JPanel pDisabled = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0,2,2));
                pDisabled.setBackground(Color.red);
                gui.add(pDisabled, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                // tweak the Color of the Metal disabled button
                UIManager.put("Button.disabledText", new Color(40,40,255));

                UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] plafs = 
                    UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
                for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo plafInfo : plafs) {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(plafInfo.getClassName());
                        JButton bEnabled = new JButton(plafInfo.getName());
                        pEnabled.add(bEnabled);
                        JButton bDisabled = new JButton(plafInfo.getName());
                        bDisabled.setEnabled(false);
                        pDisabled.add(bDisabled);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

As pointed out by kleopatra..

> it's not a solution but might be a pointer to the direction to search for a solution

Where 'it' is my answer. In fact, I suspect she hit upon the real cause with the comment:

> guessing only: here it's due to violating the one-plaf-only rule.

I second that guess.

Comment: actually, no (though I upvoted before checking, and now cant remove it :-) - it looks more like an artefact from that incomplete (?) plaf setting. As you see, even the enabled button looks wrong. To be concrete: if I run the example as-is, I see the same as the screenshot. If I change it to only set metal (2 buttons only) all looks like expected

Comment: @kleopatra  I see what you mean (it was a rather unexpected result).  (scratches head) Any idea on why it behaves that way?  As to the actual question, I suppose it comes back to the good advice of SkeetOverFlow - the OP should post an SSCCE.

Comment: no clear idea as to the why - guessing only: here it's due to violiting the one-plaf-only rule. It's erratic, though: add the metal button as last and all is well. Good thing of this example is that the OPs effect _can_ be reproduced, so up again :-)

Comment: you might want to edit the answer to emphasize the fact that it's not a solution but might be a pointer to the direction to search for a solution :-)

Comment: Done.  Hope you don't mind that I pilfered your exact words, but I couldn't think of a better way to express it.