# Set different look and feel for a component

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jdatechooser

I'm making a java application with seaglass look and feel, but I need set the default look and feel for a specific component. The component is a `JDateChooser`, but with the seaglass LAF this does not display correctly, it displays horribly.

[image]

How can I set the default look and feel for this component only?

Comment: *"..I need set the default look and feel for a specific component."*  It was determined that mixing PLAFs is a recipe for disaster.  Let me try and find a reference..

Comment: Ah yes, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7631977/418556) and pay special heed to the comments of kleopatra (a Swing guru).